# Flyway migration error via maven job on jenkins

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, migration, flyway

I have a postgresql database. The user I use to do the migration via flyway have create permissions but when I apply the migration via a jenkins maven job I get the following error:

```
07:24:06 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:5.0.2:migrate (default) on project database_repo: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:
07:24:06 [ERROR] Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from Schema History table "public"."SCHEMA_VERSION_1_2_4"
07:24:06 [ERROR] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
07:24:06 [ERROR] SQL State  : 42501
07:24:06 [ERROR] Error Code : 0
07:24:06 [ERROR] Message    : ERROR: permission denied for relation SCHEMA_VERSION_1_2_4
07:24:06 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
07:24:06 [ERROR] 
07:24:06 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
07:24:06 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

If I add the user the superadmin privileges then it starts working without any problems but I would rather not give superadmin privileges to that user.

Can anyone tell me which privileges the user needs for this to work?

Comment: Did you try add grant to INSERT into this relation?

Answer (score 0):

The user conecting to the database from the flyway should've been the owner of the database.

once I run the following command the user could connect to the database and create the tables he needed:

```
ALTER DATABASE name OWNER TO new_owner;
```